# Cannot assign the new value to variable in while loop with if statement for datetime

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop

```py
import datetime
import time

while True:
    a = 0
    b = 0

    time1 = datetime.datetime.now()       
    conditional_time1 = time1.replace(hour= 8, minute=52, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if (time1.hour == conditional_time1.hour) \
        & (time1.minute == conditional_time1.minute) \
        & (time1.second == conditional_time1.second) \
        & (time1.microsecond == conditional_time1.microsecond):
        a = 'first'

    time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    conditional_time2 = time2.replace(hour= 8, minute=53, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if (time2.hour == conditional_time2.hour) \
        & (time2.minute == conditional_time2.minute) \
        & (time2.second == conditional_time2.second) \
        & (time2.microsecond == conditional_time2.microsecond):
        b = 'second'
        
    time3 = datetime.datetime.now()
    break_time3 = time2.replace(hour= 8, minute=54, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if (time2.hour == conditional_time2.hour) \
        & (time2.minute == conditional_time2.minute):
        break
        
    lst = []
    lst.append(a)
    lst.append(b)
```

It printed out a list: `[0,0]`.

I need to get a list with: `['first', 'second']`

Comment: You'll want to use the `and` operator to connect multiple conditions, not `&`

Comment: To debug your code, you could print out whenever you set the variables `a` or `b` to ensure this happens. Also, you should probably take the time only once and the same value in all of your conditions.

Comment: `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) in Python, not a conditional one. Also, are you sure you want to compare microseconds?